# React Material UI SelectField menu items not appearing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using Material-UI 0.15.1, React 15.2.0
When I click on the SelectField dropdown I get an empty dropdown appearing with out the menu choices appearing.  When I use hardcoded MenuItems in the SelectField I see the full menu without issue.

This does not appear to be an injectTapEventPlugin as I am importing it and calling it.  My code is below:

```
render() {
var divStyle = {
  fontSize: 16
};

var mymenuItems = [
{ payload: '1', text: 'one' },
{ payload: '2', text: 'two' },
{ payload: '3', text: 'three' },
{ payload: '4', text: 'four' },
{ payload: '5', text: 'five' },
];


return (
  <div style={divStyle}>
    <SelectField
        value={this.state.selected}
        onChange={this._onSelect}
        floatingLabelText="Product"
        menuItems={mymenuItems}>
    </SelectField>      
  </div>

)
```

}

I am also getting a

> Warning: Unknown props `onItemTouchTap`, `disableAutoFocus`,
>   `onEscKeyDown` on  tag. Remove these props from the element

in the console when I click on the SelectField but I saw others had similar issues due to new React version it and it appears people think it should not affect my code (though it is very annoying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are using `menuItems`, this property is from old material-ui versions.

But its simple to fix - based on your code you can just map through the array and return `MenuItem` elements..
Example:

```
<SelectField
    value={this.state.selected}
    onChange={this._onSelect}
    floatingLabelText="Product">

    {mymenuItems.map(x => <MenuItem key={x.payload} value={x.payload} primaryText={x.text} />)}
</SelectField>
```

I'd suggest you to check the examples on the material-ui docs
http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field

Comment: Thanks Andre.  I did not see the one dynamic array example in the docs (the long example) and I prefer the old method instead of embedding the encoding into the array.  Now it appears the only way I can get to the text of the item chosen in the callback is something like: var itemSelected = this.state.myMenuOptions[index].props.primaryText.  is this correct?  Unless I keep another array without the coding embeded in it (the array has > 250 items)

Comment: @AharonHaber If you do as that example unfortunately yes.. But I suggest you to keep your objects array and map through it in the `render`, as I did in my example..

Comment: @AharonHaber if you think this is the right answer, I'd suggest you to mark it as the right one, so others can see that this question was already answered.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in your build:

```
var injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");
injectTapEventPlugin();
```

Make sure that function is ran before you render anything to page.

Reference: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/1011